# Error while Confirming Connectivity to the REST API (for Docker) curl http://localhost:8008/blocks

Tags: docker, curl, blockchain, hyperledger-sawtooth

I am trying to set up Hyperledger sawtooth testing node, so I followed  this link: [setting up a sawtooth testing node with Docker](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/app_developers_guide/docker.html#)

I have started node by using this command:  `docker-compose -f sawtooth-default.yaml up` and it running. [running node view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wy6i.jpg)

now I need to Confirm Connectivity to the REST API (for Docker):

To confirm that the REST API and validator are running and reachable from the client container, I run this curl command: `curl http://rest-api-0:8008/blocks` and it works fine [view output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVANr.jpg), but in the second step I need to check connectivity from the host computer, from a new terminal window on my host system I run this curl command: curl http://localhost:8008/blocks` and it gives this error [view error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcUD5.jpg) :

> curl:(7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8008: connection refused.

I am using the ubuntu 20.04 system, I have found some solution [link](https://medium.com/@myte/blockchain-meets-automation-part-1-4780380ae71f), but that was on the AWS server which quoted this "On AWS doing a curl http://localhost:8008/blocks gives me an error message. I resolved the issue by changing the docker container ‘hosts’ file, use AWS ec2 private IP instead.

```
cd /etc
echo AWS PRIVATE IP ADDRESS localhost > hosts
root@99a2e75d41f6:/etc# echo 10.0.1.224 localhost > hosts
root@99a2e75d41f6:/etc# cat hosts
10.0.1.224 localhost
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use this command to get correct ip address of image
**docker inspect sawtooth-rest-api-default-0 | grep IPAddress**
then replace your url to the url from ip address you have just get from previous step. example http://172.20.0.11:8008/blocks